# Menu bar missing in Krita

Tags: kubuntu, menu-bar, krita

I've just installed Krita using snap with the following command:

`sudo snap install krita`

But the menu bar is not showing up. What should I do?

Krita Version:4.4.5,
Kubuntu Version: 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl`-`M` ? That should toggle it on and off.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It didn't work. @HuHa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then remove Snap'ed version with

```
snap remove krita
```

and install older 4.2.9 version using APT:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install krita
```

If you need newer 4.4.3 version - try to use FlatPak by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.kde.krita
```

Comment: Installing version 4.2.9 using apt solved my problem. Thanks.